# Extract table-names from MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there a way to extract/export only all table-names from MySQL Workbench, not data or structure, I just want list of all tables.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql -uusername -p -e"show tables"`

Comment: Please add comment explaining your answer

Comment: HIs answer is using the mysql client on a command line, not what you asked for, but the show tables is what you need. So just type show tables into the workbench.

Answer (score 2):

use ;
show tables;
and then export as excel file you can find in my sql workbench.